# React - Component Lifecycle when pressing "back" from an external URL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

Context:
I am creating a simple web app where the user can login, select the amount they wish to pay, and then press a Pay button which redirects them to a payment gateway in order for them to pay.

Problem:
When they press the Pay button, I set a mobX observable variable to loading so as to show a loading spinner and disable the button. This works fine. However, if the user proceeds to the external payment gateway, and then press the browser Back button, on certain browsers (Firefox and Safari), my state is still loading, despite setting it to not loading on `componentDidMount`. What component lifecycle method is called when navigating to the component from the back button on all browsers?

code:

```
@observer
class DuesForm extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    private form;

    private loadingStore: LoadingStore = new LoadingStore();

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.form = React.createRef();
    }

    public componentDidMount() {
        this.loadingStore.setLoadingToComplete();
    }

    public componentWillUnmount() {
        this.loadingStore.setLoadingToComplete();
    }

    public render() {
        return (
                <form
                    name="dues-form"
                    ref={(f) => (this.form = f)}
                    method="POST"
                    action="www.external-payment-gateway.com"
                >
                    <div>
                        <h4 style={{ marginBottom: '0.5em' }}>Currency</h4>
                        <Radio.Group
                            options={currencyOptions}
                            optionType="button"
                            buttonStyle="solid"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div style={{ marginTop: '1em' }}>
                        <h4 style={{ marginBottom: '0.5em' }}>Amount</h4>
                        <InputNumber
                            type="number"
                            style={{ minWidth: '8em', justifyContent: 'center' }}
                            min={0}
                            step={0.01}
                            precision={2}
                        />
                    </div>
                    {this.loadingStore.isLoading ? (
                        <Space size="middle" style={{ marginBottom: '1em', marginTop: '1em' }}>
                            <Spin indicator={<LoadingOutlined />} />
                        </Space>
                    ) : null}
                    <div style={{ marginTop: '1.5em' }}>
                        <Button
                            className="primary-button"
                            style={{ width: '100%' }}
                            type="primary"
                            onClick={this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)}
                            disabled={this.loadingStore.isLoading}
                        >
                            Pay
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                    <PaymentForm /> // This is a hidden form given to me by the payment gateway to send the data
                </form>
        );
    }

    private handleSubmit(e: any): void {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.loadingStore.setLoadingToLoading();
        this.form.submit(); // the reason I am doing it this way is I have to fetch some data from the API before submitting
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried with ‘componentDidUpdate’?

Comment: yes, but then when I press Pay, it updates and so doesn't set to loading ever. Which means that my button is never disabled

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Comment: no it didn't work after doing a build and trying it on another device :( I am thinking of just removing the loading

Comment: Not sure if it help, but maybe kill the loading in the componentWillUnmount lifecycle to be sure

Comment: I did try that but for some reason that function isn't called when I redirect to another page

Comment: Not sure what exactly causing an issue for you. But I would definitely simplify keep a loading flag as a state in the component instead of a store.